# Apache Kafka: what is the difference between log and partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

By reading the docs and different sources, I can't quite get the difference between log and partition; they seem like synonyms, besides the log meaning maybe something more closer to the physical representation (maybe the set of segment files of a partition?) and partition more close to the abstract concept of partition, but I'm not quite sure.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: A partition is a subset of a log.  Partitions allow topics to be parallelized by splitting the data across multiple brokers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ok. In this case, what is the difference between a topic and a log then? Because a topic is a collection of partitions, or a partition a subset of a topic, so in that case is now log and topic what looks like synonyms.

Comment: In essence, a topic in Kafka is a high-level concept that producers and consumers interact with, while a log is the underlying data structure that represents how Kafka stores and manages the data within a topic's partitions. The log is an implementation detail that ensures efficient storage and retrieval of records in Kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log is a file in your FS, each log represents only one partition, but a partition can have more than one log file.
When for example you create a topic with three partitions, Kafka will create three log directories named **topic-name-partitionNumber**, with several files inside, one of those files is **00000000000000000000.log** and is called a segment, each message written to this partition is going to this file, when this file attain 1 gibibyte **log.segment.bytes** or the 168 hours since we started writing to this file **log.roll.hours** (those are default values and can be updated in your server.properties or for individual topics), kafka will roll out this file and create a new one with a different name. The new file is called active segment, Kafka will read and write from active segments but only read from rolled out one.

There is a small difference when we talk about compacted topics, but most of this still true